# During runing method in dll file following exception is occured

Tags: c#

> Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.MSXML2, Version=5.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.
>      public string getImpPointValue(int EnumSetId, string EnumId, string EnumText)
>           {

```
        int ElemeentStateTextXmlID = EnumSetId;
        string ElemeentStateTextXmlValue = EnumId.ToString();

        string[] ElemeentStateTextValue = { ElemeentStateTextXmlValue };
        string[] getUints = { EnumText };

        objDeviceAcess.GetEnumValues(ref ElemeentStateTextXmlID, ref ElemeentStateTextValue, ref getUints);

        string getUintsValue = getUints[0];

        return getUintsValue;
    }
```

Note : during executing " objDeviceAcess.GetEnumValues(ref ElemeentStateTextXmlID, ref ElemeentStateTextValue, ref getUints) " then exception occured like object refrence not set to instance of an object

Comment: Is it objDeviceAcess that is null ?

Comment: No, objDeviceAccess is not null

Answer (score 1):

you  need to  reinstall  Microsoft XML Parser and Microsoft XML Core Services (MSXML) 5.0 
here  where you  can find it
                         http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324460

Comment: Interop.MSXML2.dll file is genrated but exception is thrown like "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: you should post a sample of your code  to let us provide u the best solution

Comment: ok, during executing "GetEnumValues " method in dll file. Exception like object refrence not set to instance of an object is occurred. refer above code

Comment: why you don't use System.Xml namespace

Comment: yes with .net you have all the API to access an XML  doc built-in